# MySQL recursive cte base case

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, recursive-cte

I have a table of events for a bunch of aggregates (*order* is one of them), that I can query like

```sql
SELECT * FROM events WHERE aggregate_id = :order_id AND aggregate_type = :order_type
```

This works fine for the simple case, but it gets a bit more involved with *duplicate created* event. One of the business requirements is that an order can be duplicated (conceptually, think `move`, not `copy`). This will **close** the original order, and then the staff can continue to work on the new order. In order to show the full history of an order, it would make sense to show not only the events for the current order, but also the events on any *original orders*.

Here's a simplified example:

**Order 3**

- 10 May - shipped
- 9 May - packed
- 9 May - duplicated from *Order 2*

**Order 2**

- 9 May - closed
- 8 May - customer contacted
- 8 May - stock received
- 6 May - duplicated from *Order 1*

**Order 1**

- 6 May - closed
- 5 May - created

I have whipped up a rather simple query that works well for this case:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE original_orders(order_id) AS (
  select aggregate_id
  from events
  where aggregate_type = 'order'
    and aggregate_id = :order_id
    and event_name = 'duplicate created'
  UNION ALL
  select body->'$.duplicatedFromOrderId'
  from original_orders
    inner join events on (aggregate_type = 'order' and aggregate_id = order_id and event_name = 'duplicate created')
)
SELECT events.*
FROM events
INNER JOIN original_orders ON aggregate_id = order_id;
-- extra context from the real (not simplified) use-case:
-- I actually use the CTE twice, because "notes" are stored separately
-- INNER JOIN users ON event.user_id - to get more info
-- UNION ALL SELECT * FROM notes JOIN original_orders ON order_id = notes.object_id
```

The recursive CTE ends up selecting order ids starting from the latest order (the base case part) and then recurses by getting the original order id from the event body.
The result for the example would be a single column `order_id` with 3 rows: `(3, 2, 1)`.

The problem is that if we look at the original order (*Order 1* in this case), **no events will be shown at all**, because it doesn't have the *duplicate created* event. Thus, any order that isn't a duplicate selects nothing in the base case, so the CTE will return an empty result set.

I feel like my logic is somewhat flawed, and I'm missing the [obvious] simple way to get what I need. I've thought that in the base case I could instead search for ANY event name and GROUP BY id, thus getting an `order_id` in the base case query even if the order is not a duplicate (in a similar fashion I could use `SELECT DISTINCT` and ditch the `GROUP BY` but it's really the same thing). Like so:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE original_orders(order_id) AS (
  select aggregate_id
  from events
  where aggregate_type = 'order'
    and aggregate_id = :order_id
  group by aggregate_id
  UNION ALL
  -- ...
)
```

This feels like a workaround, so I'd love to fix my logic. What am I missing?

---

Reproducible example:

```sql
create table events
(
    id             int auto_increment,
    aggregate_type varchar(100) not null,
    aggregate_id   varchar(255) not null,
    event_name     varchar(255) not null,
    occurred_on    datetime     not null,
    body           json         not null,
    constraint events_pk
        primary key (id)
);

insert into events (aggregate_type, aggregate_id, event_name, occurred_on, body)
values ('order', 1, 'created', '2020-05-05 09:00:00', json_object()),
       ('order', 1, 'closed', '2020-05-06 09:00:00', json_object()),
       ('order', 2, 'duplicate created', '2020-05-06 09:00:00', json_object('duplicatedFromOrderId', 1)),
       ('order', 2, 'received', '2020-05-07 09:00:00', json_object()),
       ('order', 2, 'closed', '2020-05-08 09:00:00', json_object()),
       ('order', 3, 'duplicate created', '2020-05-08 09:00:00', json_object('duplicatedFromOrderId', 2)),
       ('order', 3, 'shipped', '2020-05-09 09:00:00', json_object());
```

Running the query with `:order_id = 3` should return all 7 events.

Running the query with `:order_id = 2` should return 5 events (should ignore events for order 3).

Runnning the query with `:order_id = 1` should return 2 events.

Comment: What’s the purpose of this CTE? Can’t you just select from the events table?

Comment: @Marko how would I select without the CTE (and without manually typing a "hardcoded" number of JOINs), considering that events for *Order 1* must be shown on the page for *Order 3*?

Comment: Post a sample of the events table for those 3 orders and the desired CTE output

Comment: @Marko I've added an example if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte as (
    select * from events
    where aggregate_id = :order_id
    and aggregate_type = 'order'
    union all
    select ev.* from cte 
    inner join events ev on ev.aggregate_id = cast(cte.body->'$.duplicatedFromOrderId' as UNSIGNED)
    where ev.aggregate_type = 'order'
)
select * from cte;
```